# Residues of a Meromorphic Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open connected subset of the set $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers, and $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a meromorphic function, with set of poles $A$. Let $\{z_i \}$ be an enumeration of the elements of $A$, and for any $z \in A$, let $Res_{z}(f)$ be the residue of $f$ in $z$. Does the series
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i} \frac{Res_{z_i}(f)}{z - z_i}
\end{equation}
converge? Does it absolutely converge? Does it define a meromorphic function in $\Omega$?
I should add that I have no reason to believe that the answer is in the affermative, but I don't have a great familiarity with meromorphic functions, so I couldn't build a counterexample.
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to all questions is "not in general". It may happen, but that's an exceptional case.

Clearly, if $A$ is a finite set, there are no problems.

Now consider an infinite set $A$, and a bounded domain $\Omega$. If we have e.g. the residue $1$ at all points of $A$, then show that the given series *cannot* converge. On the other hand, if the sequence of residues converges to $0$ fast enough (what "fast enough" means depends on $A$), then the given series will converge absolutely (and locally uniformly) on $\Omega\setminus A$, and so define a meromorphic function on $\Omega$.

Examples where the series converges absolutely (and locally uniformly) are however easier to construct on unbounded domains, to get some experience show that

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{z - n^2}$$

converges absolutely and locally uniformly on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{n^2 :n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, and hence defines a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Dear Daniel, thank you very much for having replied to my question. All your statements are clear to me, with one exception. I don't see how to build an example of a meromorphic function with bounded domain, having an infinite set of poles, and having residue 1 in each pole. Could you give me some hint, please?

Comment: One way to construct such a thing is the (general) Mittag-Leffler theorem. By that, if $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a domain, $P \subset U$ a subset that has no accumulation point in $U$, and $\{ r_p : p \in P\}$ a set of complex numbers, there is a meromorphic function on $U$ with (simple) poles precisely in the points of $P$, such that the residue at $p$ is $r_p$. You can even prescribe more. But we can also give an explicit example. If $f$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $z_0$, and $f$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z_0$, then $\frac{f'}{f}$ is meromorphic on that neighbourhood, and has a …

Comment: … simple pole with residue $k$ at $z_0$. So we need a function with infinitely many simple zeros on a bounded domain. We can for example take $\sin \frac{1}{z}$ on $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\} = \{ z : 0 < \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$. Then $$-\frac{\cos \frac{1}{z}}{z^2\sin \frac{1}{z}}$$ is an explicit example.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel: I would have never answered this question by myself. I haven't still studied Mittag-Leffler Theorem, but I could follow the construction of your explicit example. I only add the simple proof of your statement about $f$. Just note that in a small enough disc of center $z_0$, $f(z)=(z-z_0)^k g(z)$ and $f'(z)=(z-z_0)^{k-1} h(z)$, with $g$ and $h$ holomorphic, and such that $g(z_0)=c_k$, $h(z_0)=k c_k$, where $c_k = f^{(k)}(z_0) / (k!)$.